# Dynamically compiling scala class files at runtime in Scala 2.11

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

I have the following code that works in Scala 2.10 to compile external classes at runtime in Scala

```
/**
  * Compile scala files and keep them loaded in memory
  * @param classDir Directory storing the generated scala files
  * @throws IOException if there is problem reading the source files
  * @return Classloader that contains the compiled external classes
  */
@throws[IOException]
def compileFiles(classDir: String): AbstractFileClassLoader = {
  val files = recursiveListFiles(new File(classDir))
                  .filter(_.getName.endsWith("scala"))
  println("Loaded files: \n" + files.mkString("[", ",\n", "]"))

  val settings: GenericRunnerSettings = new GenericRunnerSettings(err => println("Interpretor error: " + err))
  settings.usejavacp.value = true
  val interpreter: IMain = new IMain(settings)
  files.foreach(f => {
    interpreter.compileSources(new BatchSourceFile(AbstractFile.getFile(f)))
  })

  interpreter.getInterpreterClassLoader()
}
```

And then elsewhere, I could use the classloader reference to instantiate classes e.g.

```
val personClass = classLoader.findClass("com.example.dynacsv.PersonData")
val ctor = personClass.getDeclaredConstructors()(0)
val instance = ctor.newInstance("Mr", "John", "Doe", 25: java.lang.Integer, 165: java.lang.Integer, 1: java.lang.Integer)
println("Instantiated class: " + instance.getClass.getCanonicalName)
println(instance.toString)
```

However the above no longer works as `getInterpreterClassLoader` method has been removed from `scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain`. Also, AbstractFileClassLoader has been moved and deprecated. It is no longer allowed to call `findClass` method in the class loader from an external package.

What is the recommended way to do the above in Scala 2.11? Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your goal is to run external scala classes in runtime, I'd suggest using eval with `scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox` (it is included in REPL, but for normal usage you have to add scala-reflect.jar):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
tb.eval(tb.parse("""println("hello!")"""))
```

You also can compile files, using `tb.compile`.

Modified with example: assume you have external file with

```
class PersonData() {
  val field = 42
}
scala.reflect.classTag[PersonData].runtimeClass
```

So you do

```
val clazz = tb.compile(tb.parse(src))().asInstanceOf[Class[_]]
val ctor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructors()(0)
val instance = ctor.newInstance()
```

Additional possibilities are (almost) unlimited, you can get full tree AST and work with it as you want:

```
showRaw(tb.parse(src)) // this is AST of external file sources
// this is quasiquote
val q"""
      class $name {
        ..$stats
      }
      scala.reflect.classTag[PersonData].runtimeClass
    """ = tb.parse(src)
// name: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeName = PersonData
// stats: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Tree] = List(val field = 42)
println(name) // PersonData
```

See official documentation for these tricks:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/intro.html

Comment: How do I get back instance of an unknown class after doing the compile? `tb.compile(tb.parse(source)).asInstanceOf[PersonData]` does not work, because PersonData is in the source being compiled. There is a working example added in the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088871/dynamically-create-case-class?noredirect=1&lq=1), would you be able to modify that to use `ToolBox`? Thanks

Comment: Can you modify sources to have reference to defined class in final statement? If yes, then all you need is to grab that class with `asInstanceOf[Class[_]]`, and use it as you want.

Comment: I mean having in source file smth like `case class PersonData(i: Int); scala.reflect.classTag[PersonData].runtimeClass`

Comment: Modified my answer with an example. Note that you have to continue using reflection to access fields.

Comment: Thanks, yes I can modify the source file and add the classTag line. With that this works now. One question: `instance.getClass.getName` gives something like: `__wrapper$1$3ec23e8228d44c638bba98e65ef2c748.__wrapper$1$3ec23e8228d44c638bba98e65ef2c748$PersonData$3`. Is there any way to get the `PersonData` as the class name?. Also, you have a typo (missed the apply) in your code for `val clazz`, please fix it so it helps someone else. It should be `val clazz = tb.compile(tb.parse(src))().asInstanceOf[Class[_]]`

Comment: Also, is there a way to specify a package name for the class? If I add `package com.example.csv` at the top of external file, it errors out. I tried with or without wrapping the package in `{ ... }`

Comment: Thanks, fixed that typo. Also added answer for first question. What about second one, I'm confused what is going on, need some research for that weird error. Can you simply ignore that package line while constructing `src` (a workaround) ?

Comment: Great, I'll leave the question open for a couple of days to see if there are any better ideas to do this, but you're answer and comments have helped me. Thanks!

Comment: I get an AbstractMethodError when calling `tb.eval`. I am executing the code sample with the `println("hello!")` in it. I have added `scala-reflect.jar` as a dependancy. I am using Scala 1.12. Any ideas?

Comment: @LlewVallis (probably you meant `2.12`). Just tried, works for me (run `App` with `scala-reflect.jar`, first code snippet works). Please check versions of your dependencies. Then, if that doesn't help, could you publish your code somewhere, so I could take a look on it?

Comment: @vsnyc 
@dveim Thanks for the detailed description. 
Did you guys ever found out the solution of getting `PersonData` as className instead of `__wrapper$1$3ec23e8228d44c638bba98e65ef2c748.__wrapper$1$3ec23e8228d44c638bba98e65ef2c748$PersonData$3`

Comment: @SumeetGupta I wasn't able to get the package name added at the time.

Comment: Hi, do you know by chance which is the maven depedency for import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler . Though "scala-reflect" library alone should be sufficient.