# Scala 2.11 & Spark 2.0.0 Create dynamically case class to encode Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to update my app from Spark 1.6.2 to 2.0.0, my problem is to create a Dataset from Dataframe (parquet that i read).

I know that i can use case class or tuple to type the Dataframe then have a Dataset but before the runtime i don't know which data will load the user, so the type of column and number of them.

To load data i read data from parquet with a SparkSession, simple like :

```
spark.read.schema(schema).parquet(dataPath)
```

schemaOfData is a StructType instantiate by an List[Map[String, String]] that contains the name of the column and his type (which is else String else Double).

I found this on StackOverflow but i struggle to understand it and guest if there isn't an easier way to solve my problem:
[Dynamically compiling scala class files at runtime in Scala 2.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137175/dynamically-compiling-scala-class-files-at-runtime-in-scala-2-11)

Thanks

Comment: From what i read the performance should be superior then the use of map without of changing all the legacy code made in my app, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433419/encoder-error-while-trying-to-map-dataframe-row-to-updated-row

Comment: Coding type-generic logic in Scala requiring to obtain the type of something at run-time can be quite cumbersome. Spark by-pass this using expressions, enabling a SQL-like behaviour for column types (which are therefore checked at run-time). This is why you probably want to leverage the type genericity of DataFrames, or the flexibility of Row to handle that, rather than to have to do everything yourself. Or?

Answer (score 0):

Create implicit conversion from spark datatypes to Scala native data types.

Then map that type to schema with StructFields of Spark DataFrame

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
  import org.apache.spark.sql.types._


    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("Movies Reviews")
      .config("spark.master", "local")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    val someDF = Seq(
      (8, "bat"),
      (64, "mouse"),
      (-27, "horse")
    ).toDF("number", "word")

    someDF.printSchema()

    def schemaCaseClass(schema:StructType, className:String)
                       (implicit sparkTypeScala:DataType => String):String = {
      def structField(col:StructField):String = {
        val sparkTypes = sparkTypeScala(col.dataType)
        col match {
          case x if x.nullable => s"  ${col.name}:Option[$sparkTypes]"
          case _ => s"  ${col.name}:$sparkTypes"
        }
      }

    val fieldsName = schema.map(structField).mkString(",\n  ")
    s"""
       |case class $className (
       |  $fieldsName
       |)
    """.stripMargin
    }

    implicit val scalaTypes:DataType => String = {
        case _: ByteType => "Byte"
        case _: ShortType => "Short"
        case _: IntegerType => "Int"
        case _: LongType => "Long"
        case _: FloatType => "Float"
        case _: DoubleType => "Double"
        case _: DecimalType => "java.math.BigDecimal"
        case _: StringType => "String"
        case _: BinaryType => "Array[Byte]"
        case _: BooleanType => "Boolean"
        case _: TimestampType => "java.sql.Timestamp"
        case _: DateType => "java.sql.Date"
        case _: ArrayType => "scala.collection.Seq"
        case _: MapType => "scala.collection.Map"
        case _: StructType => "org.apache.spark.sql.Row"
        case _ => "String"
    }


    println(schemaCaseClass(someDF.schema, "someDF"))
```

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56049049/edit) some explanation to your answer