# Calling Method in Scala from User Input

Tags: scala, reflection

I have a user input:

`val method = """doReplace(doReplace("ab","a","x"),"b","y")"""`

How can I invoke this method at run-time using Scala:

```
object test2 {

  def doReplace(str: String, oldChar: String, newChar: String) = {
    str.replace(oldChar, newChar)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val method = """doReplace(doReplace("ab","a","x"),"b","y")"""

  }

}
```

Comment: it's possible to use reflection API, but you still need to do a lot of work parsing the user input to find the method name... (unless you restrict the user input a lot)

Answer (score 3):

If the user should only be able to call certain methods or have a simple grammar, you may write a simple parser that uses reflection. [Scala fastparse](http://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/) is a really great utilty.

If the user should be able to enter arbitrary scala code, you could use a [scala implementation of the JSR 223 scripting api](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-874) or you can compile the code at runtime as describe in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137175/dynamically-compiling-scala-class-files-at-runtime-in-scala-2-11).

Be aware that this allows to execute arbitrary code on your machine. Do not expose this interface.