# Creating some random case class dynamically using List[Strings] or Array[Strings]

Tags: scala, case-class

Without using **shapeless** library, can we create a **case class dynamically** using some bunch of Strings? (Array of strings or list of strings)

I have a list of strings and I want to some how create a case class instance so that I can map them to some other table.

For example, let's say, these are the strings

```
DRUG_NAME, DRUG_TYPE, COMPANY, STATE, OFFICER
```

I want them to be in case class, like this:

```
case class DrugStore(DRUG_NAME: String, DRUG_TYPE: String, COMPANY: String, STATE: String, OFFICER: String)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088871/dynamically-create-case-class

Comment: https://github.com/julianpeeters/case-class-generator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use reflection for that:

```
  classOf[DrugStore]
    .getConstructors 
    .head
    .newInstance(listOfParameters)
    .asInstanceOf[DrugStore]
```