# Building Reads converter and case class at runtime in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6, play-json

I have a file that contains the following array of JSON objects:

```
[
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": 1111
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": 2222
    },
    {
      "type": "mobile",
      "number": 3333
    }
  ]
```

In Play Framework 2.x I would define an implicit Reads converter to read the file and convert it to a Scala structure:

```
implicit val implicitRead : Reads[MyClass] = (
      (JsPath \ "type").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "number").read[Int]
)  (MyClass.apply _)
```

the Scala case class defined as:

```
case class MyClass (myType: String, myNumber: Int)
```

and parsing the JSON with:

```
val json = // file record content    
json.validate[MyClass] match {
  case s: JsSuccess[MyClass] => {
    val myObject: MyClass = s.get
    // do something with myObject
  }
  case e: JsError => {
    // error handling flow
  }
```

Now, my problem is that I know the structure of the JSON file *only* at `runtime`, not at `compilation time`. Is it possible to build both the implicit Reads converter and the case class at `runtime`?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088871/dynamically-create-case-class) can help to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `case classes` directly with `play-json`:

Change the `case class` to:

```
case class MyClass (`type`: String, number: Int)
```

Add the `json-formatter` to the companion object:

```
object MyClass {
  implicit val format = Json.format[MyClass]
}
```

The `validate` function looks now:

```
val myClass = // file record content    
json.validate[Seq[MyClass]] match {
  case JsSuccess(myClasses, _) => myClasses
  case e: JsError =>  // handle error case
}
```

That's all you need. If you are not happy with the parameter names, you can use a Wrapper case class.

Comment: This works, but how to generate at runtime the `MyClass` case class and object? Also, I think you have a typo, do you mean `myClass` instead of `json` in the validate function?

Comment: Why would anyone want to "generate at runtime" when there is a safer solution at compile time?

Comment: @ps0604 as cchantep already asked, there is no reason why you shouldn't create MyClass statically. Just add them in your code and you are ready to go.
- and I fixed the typo, thanks