# scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed: cannot initialize the compiler due to java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I want to pass a scala file containing a case class so my application compiles this case class during run time and start using it.

The main reason why I am doing this is because I want to avoid rebuilding my code every time the case class changes. So would be better to pass it as a parameter (in case you are wondered, the operations with this case class are generic so it is not required any rework in the transformations)

I was using these [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12122939/1773841), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088871/dynamically-create-case-class) and [post3](https://www.programcreek.com/scala/scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox) as references. So far my application looks like this:

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.tools.reflect._

object TestCompile {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val path = "C:\\myWorkspace\\entity\\TestClass.scala"
    val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
    val src = Source.fromFile(path).mkString.stripMargin
    val clazz = tb.compile(tb.parse(src))().asInstanceOf[Class[_]]

  }
}
```

The file **TestClass.scala** is like this:

```
case class TestClass(
         val value : String,
         val timeStamp : Long,
         val rowKey : String,
         val columnFamily : String
)
```

But I am getting an exception in

```
val clazz = tb.compile(tb.parse(src))().asInstanceOf[Class[_]]
```

Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError:
>   reflective compilation has failed: cannot initialize the compiler due
>   to java.lang.VerifyError:
>   scala/tools/reflect/ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal  at
>   scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$api$.liftedTree1$1(ToolBoxFactory.scala:344)
>     at
>   scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$api$.compiler$lzycompute(ToolBoxFactory.scala:330)
>     at
>   scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$api$.compiler(ToolBoxFactory.scala:329)
>     at
>   scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$.liftedTree2$1(ToolBoxFactory.scala:356)
>     at
>   scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$.apply(ToolBoxFactory.scala:354)
>     at
>   scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl.parse(ToolBoxFactory.scala:413)
>     at TestCompile$.main(App.scala:17)  at TestCompile.main(App.scala)
>   Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError:
>   scala/tools/reflect/ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal  at
>   scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$api$.liftedTree1$1(ToolBoxFactory.scala:334)

Below is the dependency I am using, however I tried with other versions always getting the same error:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.6</version>
</dependency>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce `VerifyError`.

I have

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
```

in the line `val clazz = tb.compile(tb.parse(src))().asInstanceOf[Class[_]]`.

`tb.compile(tb.parse(src))` has type `() => Any`, so `tb.compile(tb.parse(src))()` has type `Any`.

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/reflect/ToolBox.scala#L129

Remove `.asInstanceOf[Class[_]]`.

Also see [Causes of getting a java.lang.VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror)

Answer (score 1):

I got some time to test this today. The main problem I think is that the last expected line `scala.reflect.classTag[TestClass].runtimeClass` is missing in **TestClass.scala**.

One other important thing to remember is that `scala-compiler.jar` should also be in your class path.

Once I resolved that, I ran into another problem with Java/Scala object conversion. You have two options, make the `timeStamp` field, either a `String` or `Java.lang.Long`. Since the String conversion is trivial, I've given below example for `Java.lang.Long`.

With the above changes, my **TestClass.scala** looks like below:

```
case class TestClass(
                      value : String,
                      timeStamp : java.lang.Long,
                      rowKey : String,
                      columnFamily : String
                    ) {}

scala.reflect.classTag[TestClass].runtimeClass
```

I copied it to `/tmp/` directory for testing.

### Testing

My **TestCompile.scala** looks like below:

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.tools.reflect._

object TestCompile {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val path = "/tmp/TestClass.scala"
    val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
    val src = Source.fromFile(path).mkString.stripMargin
    println(src)
    val clazz = tb.compile(tb.parse(src))().asInstanceOf[Class[_]]

    val ctor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructors()(0)
    val instance = ctor.newInstance("My value", new java.lang.Long(1234567890L), "Row1", "Column1")
    println(instance.toString)

  }
}
```

#### Output

```
TestClass(My value,1234567890,Row1,Column1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you lost dependency Add those dependency to your pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.8</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]